# Normal Distribution & Modulus

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I was doing some normal distribution questions and was stumped when I faced this question. Hope you guys can give me a hand here.

**Question**
If the annual precipitation $X$ in a city is a normal variable, with mean $50$cm and standard deviation $10$cm. Determine the following.
The probability that $X$ is within $5$cm from the mean annual precipitation

**The answer**
The probability that $X$ is within $5$cm from the mean annual precipitation is
$P(|X - 50| < 5) = P(|(X-50/10)| < 5/10).$

**My Confusion**
Why is  $P(|(X-50/10)| < 5/10)$ not P(|(X-50**-50**/10)| < **5/10**).  And why divide the $5$ with $10?$

Thank you guys

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Tried to edit your Question, but couldn't figure out the **'s, so maybe you can clarify that part. Hope one of the Answers is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \sim N(0,1)$, hence we divide by the standard deviation.

When we have an inequality $a \le b$ we can divide both sides by the same positive scalar and the statements are equivalent.

Comment: Fine answer (+1), but I wanted to give a little more detail about dividing by 10.

Answer (score 1):

If $X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 50, \sigma=10),$ then

$$P(45 < X < 55) = P\left(\frac{45 - 50}{10}< \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} < \frac{55 - 50}{10}\right)\\
= P(-0.5 < Z < 0.5) = 0.3829,$$
where $Z \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0, 1),$ the *standard* normal distribution.

The displayed equation shows the process of 'standardization', which makes it possible to find the (approximate) probability from printed tables of the standard normal distribution. For example, you can find from such tables that
$P(0 < Z < 0.5)   = 0.1915,$ from which the result can be obtained by symmetry as
$P(-0.5 < Z < 0.5) = 2(0.1915) =  0.3830,$ correct to three places.

Alternatively, statistical software or statistical calculators can be used to evaluate the original expression $P(45 < X < 55) = 0.3829249$ directly. The result from
R statistical software is shown below.

```
diff(pnorm(c(45,55), 50, 10))
[1] 0.3829249
```

The left panel below shows the density function of $\mathsf{Norm}(50, 10)$ and the panel at right shows the standard normal density function. In both panels, the total area beneath the density function is $1$ and the desired probability is
the area between the vertical dotted lines.

[image]